# Find cumulative sum of a list while reading data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, cumsum

I want to find `cumulative sum of the list`

I am reading 30 similar csv files located in the folder deg_pvsyst_runs. Files are named as:

> ```
>  "Energy_Base_Year00_-0.6%modqual.csv",
>  "Energy_Base_Year01_-0.3%modqual.csv",  ......,  
>  "Energy_Base_Year30_-8.4%modqual.csv
> ```

"

I am reading E_Grid Column (After skipping rows 0-9, 11 and 12 which has header info) in the each of the above csv files. Please suggest

a) If there is a shorter/easier way to read csv while skipping rows as opposed to what I have done (`skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12]`)

b) If using `itertools` method or `cumsum` function would be a better option to calculate the cumulative sum of list called `Cumulative_Annual_Deg`

CODE:

```
import os, csv, re
import pandas as pd
from itertools import accumulate

Year, Degradation, Mean_EP, Annual_Deg, Cumulative_Annual_Deg =[],[],[],[],[]


cwd = os.getcwd()
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(cwd + '\\' + 'deg_pvsyst_runs') if f.endswith('.csv')]

for i,j in enumerate(csv_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + "\\deg_pvsyst_runs\\" + j, skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12])
    Mean_EP.append(df['E_Grid'].sum()/10**6)
    Annual_Deg.append((Mean_EP[i-1] - Mean_EP[i])/Mean_EP[i-1])
    Cumulative_Annual_Deg.append(list(accumulate(Annual_Deg[i])))
```

ERROR:

```
Cumulative_Annual_Deg.append(list(accumulate(Annual_Deg[i])))

   TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

EDIT:

`Annual_Deg` is list consisting of delta (% change) calculate between the csv files. I want to calculate `Cumulative_Annual_Deg` to calculate cumulative sum.

**Desired output :**

- `Annual_Mean_EP = [9559.88, 9533.31, 9506.67,...,8731.85]`

  `Annual_Deg =     [0, 0.00278, 0.00279,...,0.00297]`

  `Cumulative_Annual_Deg' = [0, 0.00278, 0.00557, ..., 0.08661]`

**OR Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: accumulate takes a list as an argument , you are providing a float. are you doing calculations across the files ? 
(Mean_EP[i-1] - Mean_EP[i] --> where i is ith Csv file, This means you are calculating across the files. This could be the issue.
Could you provide a sample data ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes I am doing calculations in between the csv files to calculate the delta ,i.e. `Annual_Deg`. Then I want to produce a list of cumulative sum

Comment: Also edited with sample output desired from the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative sum could be calculated after the list is calculated. So the accumulate line should be brought outside the for loop.
Replace following line

```
    Cumulative_Annual_Deg.append(list(accumulate(Annual_Deg[i])))
```

with

```
Cumulative_Annual_Deg = list(accumulate(Annual_Deg))
```

You can find more info about itertools on https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions